# Error thrown in Google's Inception-v3 fine-tuning script

Tags: python, tensorflow, runtime-error, bazel

When following the [Readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-retrain-a-trained-model-on-the-flowers-data) to fine-tune Google's Inception-v3 image classification model, I get the error:

`File "/Path/to/Model/bazel-bin/inception/flowers_train.runfiles/inception/inception/slim/ops.py", line 88, in batch_norm
    initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
TypeError: zeros_initializer() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

This occurs after running the final command:

```
   bazel-bin/inception/flowers_train \
  --train_dir="${TRAIN_DIR}" \
  --data_dir="${FLOWERS_DATA_DIR}" \
  --pretrained_model_checkpoint_path="${MODEL_PATH}" \
  --fine_tune=True \
  --initial_learning_rate=0.001 \
  --input_queue_memory_factor=1
```

I have 0 idea whats going on here as this error gets thrown from a python file written by the TF team. Additionally, being a TF newbie, I do not know my way around enough to attempt a deep debugging session. Just by looking at the path from the error, there might be an issue with the script running TF slim code?

Anyhow, I am running macOS Sierra with Python 3.6 and the TensorFlow Python API r0.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out this error was thrown if the current installation of tensorflow did not have the most recent tensorflow-slim code. Install directions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim).