# TypeError: zeros_initializer() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run the inception example from Tensorflow: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

However, I am getting this error:

> TypeError: zeros_initializer() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

When I looked for a solution, there were mainly two: 
 
1. changing `zeros_initializer` & `ones_initializer` to `zeros_initializer()` & `ones_initializer()`, but they were already this way. 
 
2. Upgrading Tensorflow to its latest version, which I did by this: 
`sudo pip  install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

Then I upgraded the files using this command: 
 
`tf_upgrade.py --infile foo.py --outfile foo-upgraded.py`

None of the above worked.

**Notes:** 
 I checked my TF version by this command: 
 
`python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'` 
 
which gave this result:

> 0.12.1

I have also tried to take out the parenthesis from the function but then it did not work and gave a different error

> TypeError: ones_initializer() got multiple values for keyword argument 'dtype'

**UPDATE** 
 
1. Here is the code that has the problem
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/ops.py 
2. The topic here discuses the same issue ([Error thrown in Google's Inception-v3 fine-tuning script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769301/error-thrown-in-googles-inception-v3-fine-tuning-script)) but I checked my version of slim by using:

`python -c "import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim; eval = slim.evaluation.evaluate_once"`
and 
`python -c "from nets import cifarnet; mynet = cifarnet.cifarnet"`

both run without error

Comment: you sure it is not looking for the calling object (self)?

Comment: @MHornbacher I don't think so, I am using the exact code from the rep. which seems working for most ppl.

Comment: Can you post the code so people can see and test?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code uses `initializer=tf.zeros_initializer()`. But as you see [`tf.zeros_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros_initializer) has a required attribute `shape` which is not provided by your example.

I assume that in the previous versions this argument was not required. You have 2 options:

- find the shape and pass it properly
- change it to `tf.constant_initializer(0.0)` (have not tested whether it works)

Comment: I am not sure I'll be able to find the shape. I tried the second method and got this error: "TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead."